# localhost:8000 loads infinitely without any results or error message

Tags: networking, localhost

I tried to use localhost.run and localtunnel to make my localhost publicly accessible over the internet. It didn't work and I ended up with localhost:8000 loading  infinitely even when I haven't started any server. I restarted my computer several times but the issue persists.

Comment: From where you are accessing it : same pc you have start  your server | another pc

Comment: no i stopped making it public and now i cant access it on my pc

Comment: From what method you make it public...VPN tunnelling...?

Comment: i cancelled all of it

Comment: i tried localhost.run first, then localtunnel but they didnt work